# Why is a websocket address (ws://etc) considered URI and not URL?

Tags: url, websocket, uri

I understand that any URL is also a URI but `ws://example.com` also contains information on *how* (`ws`) and *where* (`example.com`).

As I understand the main difference between URL and URI is that a URL also contains information on where to *locate* the resource.

Comment: I was asking myself the same thing this morning acutally. My guess is that URI is used as a more generic way of naming an item. A bit like asking what vehicle someone drives, which could be a car or a truck, even though the more likely name would be car since this is the majority. https://danielmiessler.com/study/difference-between-uri-url/